# Sorting problems for a vector of class objects as a member function

Tags: c++, sorting, oop, vector, member-functions

I'm doing oop for the first time and I'm struggling with making some member functions for a class called PersonList. I have only finished the classes that the PersonList class is made of, and I've got everything else in the class to work (so far). The problem is that the sort functions won't compile, this is the class definition for PersonList:

## include "Person.h"

## include

class PersonList {
    private:

```
std::vector<Person> dataVector;
std::string fileName;

public:

// Member functions
std::string getFileName () const;
void setFileName (std::string pFileName);
Person getPerson (const PersonList, size_t pIndex)const;
size_t getNumberOfEntries (const PersonList) const;
void sortName ();
void sortPersnr ();
void sortShoenr ();
void readFromFile ();
void writeToFile (const PersonList);

void addPerson(Person);
bool sNameSorter (Person const& lhs, Person const&rhs);
bool sPersnrSorter (Person const& lhs, Person const &rhs);
bool sShoenrSorter (Person const&lhs, Person const&rhs);
```

};

## endif //DT019G_PERSONLIST_H

This is the sort functions:

```
// sorts the database according to the specified sorter.
void PersonList::sortName (){
    std::sort(dataVector.begin(), dataVector.end(), &PersonList::sNameSorter);
}
// sorts the database according to the specified sorter.
void PersonList::sortPersnr (){
    std::sort(dataVector.begin(), dataVector.end(), &PersonList::sPersnrSorter);
}
// sorts the database according to the specified sorter.
void PersonList::sortShoenr (){
    std::sort(dataVector.begin(), dataVector.end(), &PersonList::sShoenrSorter);
}
```

This is the sorter functions:

```
bool PersonList::sNameSorter (Person const& lhs, Person const&rhs){
    std::string lhLast=lhs.name.getLastName(), rhLast=rhs.name.getLastName(), lhFirst=lhs.name.getFirstName(),
    rhFirst=rhs.name.getFirstName();
    for (char & i : lhLast){
        if (i>64 && i<91)
            i=i+32;}
    for (char & i : rhLast){
        if (i>64 && i<91)
            i=i+32;}
    if (lhLast != rhLast)
        return lhLast < rhLast;
    for (char & i : lhFirst){
        if (i>64 && i<91)
            i=i+32;}
    for (char & i : rhFirst){
        if (i>64 && i<91)
            i=i+32;}
    if (lhFirst != rhFirst)
        return lhFirst < rhFirst;
}
// Use the given values and check which is larger, returns a bool with the answer for the sort function to deal with.
// I have to chose what happens if the values are the same, otherwise it will throw an exception.
// (The sort demands this)
bool PersonList::sPersnrSorter (Person const& lhs, Person const&rhs) {
    if (lhs.getPersNr()==rhs.getPersNr())
        return lhs.getPersNr()>rhs.getPersNr();
    if (lhs.getPersNr()!=rhs.getPersNr())
        return lhs.getPersNr()>rhs.getPersNr();
}
// Use the given values and check which is larger, returns a bool with the answer for the sort function to deal with.
// I have to chose what happens if the values are the same, otherwise it will throw an exception.
// (The sort demands this)
bool PersonList::sShoenrSorter(Person const &lhs, Person const &rhs) {
    if (lhs.getSkoNr()==rhs.getSkoNr())
        return rhs.getSkoNr()>rhs.getSkoNr();
    if (lhs.getSkoNr()!= rhs.getSkoNr())
        return lhs.getSkoNr()>rhs.getSkoNr();
}
```

And here comes the error messages:

```
PersonList.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xutility(617): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xutility(616): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'bool std::_Debug_lt_pred<_Pr&,Person&,Person&,0>(bool(__thiscall PersonList::* &)(const Person &,const Person &),_Ty1,_Ty2) noexcept(<expr>)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Pr=bool (__thiscall PersonList::* )(const Person &,const Person &),
            _Ty1=Person &,
            _Ty2=Person &
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3440): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<_RanIt,_RanIt> std::_Partition_by_median_guess_unchecked<_RanIt,_Pr>(_RanIt,_RanIt,_Pr)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _RanIt=Person *,
            _Pr=bool (__thiscall PersonList::* )(const Person &,const Person &)
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3466): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Sort_unchecked<Person*,_Fn>(_RanIt,_RanIt,int,_Pr)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Fn=bool (__thiscall PersonList::* )(const Person &,const Person &),
            _RanIt=Person *,
            _Pr=bool (__thiscall PersonList::* )(const Person &,const Person &)
        ]
C:\Users\karlj\kagy1901_solutions_vt20\Laboration_3\src\PersonList.cpp(31): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::sort<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,bool(__thiscall PersonList::* )(const Person &,const Person &)>(const _RanIt,const _RanIt,_Pr)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=Person,
            _RanIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Person>>>,
            _Pr=bool (__thiscall PersonList::* )(const Person &,const Person &)
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xutility(617): error C2056: illegal expression
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3376): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3380): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3390): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3402): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1423~1.281\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
```

Please help me, I don't really understand where the problem lies, why doesn it say that it doesn't evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments, i thought I had given it in my sorters.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that non-static member functions need an object to be called. Calling your method would be like this:

```
PersonList a,b,c;
a.sNameSorter(b,c);
```

However, you want to compare 2 elements, not 3. The easy fix is to declare those comparison functions as `static` so they can be called without an instance.

Also all your compotations for `i` in `sNameSorter` look a bit weird. It seems like the only thing that effects the return value is the last lines:

```
if (lhFirst != rhFirst)
    return lhFirst < rhFirst;
```

And here the problem is that you do not return a value in case the condition is `false`. I suppose you want instead:

```
return lhsFirst < rhFirst;
```

If `lhFrist == rhFirst` this will already return `false`.